# Interpretation of "when"

Tags: nouns, prepositional-phrases

I'm not sure whether this sentence can be interpreted differently depending on the interpretation of "when" in this context:

> Organizations employ regular marketing when they decide to cut prices
>   during a season.

I'd like to know if this sentence can be glossed as approximatelly: It is considered to be a "regular marketing" when organizations cut prices during a season (as opposed to, e.g. extreme marketing which consists of different kinds of measures).

Or the only available interpretation is the one where "when" is interpreted as "at the time when" or "in situations when" or similar, and this sentence is to be understood as: Cutting prices during a season is performed by employing regular marketing techniques.

Comment: Yes, the sentence can be read both ways - using *when* to mark a *definition* of regular marketing, or using *when* to mark the *use* of regular marketing.

Comment: @Lawrence In the case of a definition, wouldn't one use 'if'? "Organizations employ regular marketing if they decide to cut prices during a season."

Comment: @Keepthesemind "If" works as well, and can also be read both ways.

Comment: {I'm exploring some of your posts, as you might have deduced by now:)} Yes, and as you point out, there's even more ambiguity as 'when' can be temporal or equivalent to 'if and when'.